# Facebook's like button inside a JQuery Tools' tab

Tags: tabs, facebook-like, jquery-tools

I have added Facebook's like button inside the first tab of a JQuery Tools' tabs.

When the page is loaded the first tab opens and Facebook's like button appears, this works as expected, but when you click on the second/third/... tab and then return to the first tab, Facebook's like button does not appear any more...

The following is what I added to the first tab for the addition of the like button:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

and placed the following code where I want the button to appear in the first tab:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.mysite.com/example/thisPage" data-send="false" data-layout="box_count" data-width="60" data-show-faces="false"></div>
```

Any idea what's happening here, and how to reload the like button every time the first tab is loaded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing this has to do with AJAX and of course you need to reload the FB button after you call it in with AJAX. Add this to the end of your function to reinitialize Facebook and load the Like button:

```
FB.XFBML.parse();
```

Comment: I don't have any FB initialized anywhere, I see some questions where an FB was initialized with appid and channelUrl... I don't want to add an appid and channel just for a like button. Isn't there a different way to reinitialize the button, since it did work the first time, but doesn't appear after accessing other tabs and then returning to the first tab (that should include the like button but doesn't anymore).

Comment: Thanks, your solution, seems to have the done the job after all. Right after the script I added it, but with a small and very necessary addition: try
            {
                FB.XFBML.parse();
            }
            catch(e)
            {

            } because without the try catch statement, it stops at the FB.XFBML.parse(); and doesn't continue on with the rest of the script (where I continue to load other social buttons...). I'm not sure if this is the right solution but this way the like button appears, and the script doesn't stop at that parse line...